# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'ttest_ind'

Tags: pandas, numpy, data-science, scipy.stats

I am trying to perform a t-test with the following. It worked initially. But, now, it is showing the following error,

**'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'ttest_ind'**

```
col=list(somecolumns)
for i in col:
    x = np.array(data1[data1.LoanOnCard == 0][i]) 
    y = np.array(data1[data1.LoanOnCard == 1][i])
    t, p_value  = stats.ttest_ind(x,y, axis = 0,equal_var=False) 
    if p_value < 0.05:  # Setting our significance level at 5%
        print('Rejecting Null Hypothesis. Loan holders and non-Loan holders are not same for',i,'P value is %.2f' %p_value)
    else:
        print('Fail to Reject Null Hypothesis. Loan holders and non-Loan holders are  same for',i,'P value is %.2f' %p_value)
```

I am struggling to find an answer to this. Cant able to resolve.

Comment: It's not clear what `stats` is in this code. You say it worked before, have you by any chance made a variable called `stats`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `from scipy import stats` to your code.

If you already did it, this means you likely overwrote `stats` with another object. Then you can do `import scipy.stats` and use `scipy.stats.ttest_ind` instead of `stats.ttest_ind`